# Подключение к серверу с помощью Servlet и jetty

Tags: java, веб-программирование, xml, servlet

Не получается подключиться к Servlet. Дальше ошибка - HTTP ERROR 503 Подскажите в чем проблема?

Файл web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>controlServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Servlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>controlServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Класс Servlet:

```
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.getWriter().write("<html><body>GET response</body></html>");
 }
}
```

Файл pom точно настроен правильно. Подозреваю, что ошибка может быть в указанной директории в web.xml к классу Servlet, но испробовал много вариантов.

Структура проэкта :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Структура проекта не совсем правильная . Ваша директория webapp не объявлена в идеи как web resource folder. Советую пересоздать проект , выбрав шаблон web-application.

Comment: @aleshka-batman Создавал с шаблоном web-application, сейчас пересоздал - ничего  не изменилось..

Comment: [WARNING] Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@5e742e4{/,file:///Users/valik/Desktop/servletConnect/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{file:///Users/valik/Desktop/servletConnect/src/main/webapp/}
MultiException[javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Class loading error for holder MyServlet@8b8002d9==Servlet,jsp=null,order=-1,inst=false, javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Class loading error for holder MyServlet@8b8002d9==Servlet,jsp=null,order=-1,inst=false]